# Anchor tags with rails 4 working weird

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

Ok so I've encountered a very very weird problem that has got me staying up late but I finally figured out whats wrong however, the solution is not ideal and I would like to know what is happening. Better yet, how to fix it.

I have a page seperated with many div tags with the id class. I have other pages that are done the same way with no problems at all when I try to link to a particular section of a page from another page with the following methods. However, the problem occurs when the page Im linking to has not enough content.. but still is at least scrollable length.. When clicking on the links that way, instead of moving to the desired section, it just moves towards the bottom.

For instance if you clicked on this website, http://aquaticshelp.com/aquascape/getting-started#aquascape-main-plants and clicked on the "Preparing your plant section" you will see what I mean. This is a very undesirable behavior and Im not sure where to go from here.

```
<%= link_to  'Section 1', route_path(anchor: "section-1"), class: "h4" %>

<div id="section-1">
</div>

<div id="section-2">
</div>

<div id="section-3">
</div>
```

EDIT: Added some screen shots for clarity of question

Below is where you click and contains the following code

```
<%= link_to aquascape_plants_prep_path(anchor: "aquascape-plants-prep-intro") do %>
          <%= image_tag("aquascaping/start/plant_prep_img.jpg", size:"140x140", class: "img-circle center-block")%>
          <%= link_to  'Preparing the Plants', aquascape_plants_prep_path(anchor: "aquascape-plants-prep-intro"), class: "h4" %>
        <% end %>
```

[image]

The following is where it directs me to regardless of the anchor tag
[image]

Where I want it to go, and it does if I click on the following

```
<%= link_to 'Intro', "#aquascape-plants-prep-intro" %>
```

[image]

Comment: Do you mean that you want, for instance, `#section-3` to be at the top of the screen despite the fact that there is not enough text below it to fill the screen? I suspect there is a clever CSS trick for that, but I cannot think of good keywords right now...

Comment: That is correct however if you clicked on the link I provided you will notice that there is in fact more than enough space for it to be at the top of the screen

Comment: I think [this might be a usable hack](http://superuser.com/a/872654/347185)? Note that the behaviour of only scrolling so far that the end of the page is at the bottom of the screen is the default in most browsers, AFAIK.

Comment: That did not seem to work for me, Id also like to point out that if you click on the link, under quick navigation it uses the same link_to methods but it works flawlessly.

Comment: Hmm, maybe your browser has different behaviour or screen is larger? Could you post screenshots of what both the good and bad behaviour look like, as I get the same result for both.

Comment: I added some screenshots hopefully they are clearer